# How does GCC handle such a nested lambda where 'this' is getting captured

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda, c++17, this

I have this piece of code with nested lambdas and both sort of capturing 'this':

```
class MyClass2 {
public:
    int value;

    MyClass2(int initialValue) : value(initialValue) {}

    void executeLambda() {
        auto outerLambda = [this]()  {
            value++;
            auto innerLambda = [*this]() mutable {
                value++;
            };
            innerLambda();
        }; 
        outerLambda();
    }
};
```

[cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/s/547192d9) shows the compiler transformation as below:

```
class MyClass2  /* size: 4, align: 4 */
{
  
  public: 
  int value;                      /* offset: 0, size: 4 */
  inline MyClass2(int initialValue)
  : value{initialValue}
  {
  }
  
  inline void executeLambda()
  {
        
    class __lambda_10_28  /* size: 8, align: 8 */
    {
      public: 
      inline void operator()() const
      {
        __this->value++;
                
        class __lambda_12_32  /* size: 4, align: 4 */
        {
          public: 
          inline /*constexpr */ void operator()()
          {
            (&__this)->value++;
          }
          
          private: 
          MyClass2 __this;                /* offset: 0, size: 4 */
          
          public:
          __lambda_12_32(const MyClass2 & _this)
          : __this{_this}
          {}
          
        };
        
        __lambda_12_32 innerLambda = __lambda_12_32{*this}; // LINE_UNDER_CONSIDERATION
        innerLambda.operator()();
      }
      
      private: 
      MyClass2 * __this;              /* offset: 0, size: 8 */
      
      public:
      __lambda_10_28(MyClass2 * _this)
      : __this{_this}
      {}
      
    };
    
    __lambda_10_28 outerLambda = __lambda_10_28{this};
    static_cast<const __lambda_10_28>(outerLambda).operator()();
  }
  
  // inline constexpr MyClass2(const MyClass2 &) noexcept = default;
};
```

Please refer to the line marked as "**LINE_UNDER_CONSIDERATION**".

`*this` that refers to the class `__lambda_10_28` is being passed to the constructor that is taking `MyClass2`'s object as an argument. How is that even correct? From the test case's point of view, it is correct that the constructor takes in the `MyClass2` argument because we are capturing that only in the `innerLambda`.

Seeing such a transformation of this piece of code, I'm curious as to how does GCC know that the `this` that is getting passed is of the class `MyClass2` and not the internally created lambda class?

Comment: not an answer, I suppose `*this` in the line refers to `*this` in your original code, ie a `MyClass2`. cppinsight is cool, but not perfect. I have seen it before to produce confusing output. And by the nature of what it does, the code it produces doesnt follow the same rules as the code you write

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai Yes you're right, but doesn't lambdas translate to classes internally? How will `*this` refer to `MyClass2` if that happens?

Comment: `this` has special rules as far as lambdas are concerned. It is true that lambdas are instances of anonymous classes, and, in theory, `this` inside the lambda is meaningful as referring to the instance of the anonymous class. However, using `this`, willy-nilly, in a lambda will throw a compiler error. `this` "busts through" the lambdas, and always refers to the non-lambda class that the lambda is instantiated in. The usual rules for captures apply, then.

Comment: The compiler must do **AS IF** lambdas were instances of anonymous class. We have no idea how it works internally really. The `*this` of the line under consideration is clearly a mishaps from cppinsight.

Comment: for a quick sanity check you can try to compile cppinsights output with gcc https://godbolt.org/z/Pqe3zbe48, to see that the output isnt actually what gcc uses to compile. Afaik the output is just some hypothetical-twilight-would-be something in between the code you write and what the compiler makes out of it, good for illustration, but not exactly what the compiler actually does internally

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I get it, but let's see it like this. Lambda is converted into a class internally. How the compiler knows that `*this` is referring to `MyClass2`? Because you see `*this` is inside another lambda (or a class).

Comment: Is it possible to somewhere see how does the compiler actually handles all of this? (Will assembly make sense?)

Comment: The compiler knows because it is compiling The Fine Program, and knows which classes it is currently compiling. When it's chewing through the text of the lambda the compiler doesn't suffer some kind of an amnesia, and forget that the lambda is declared inside a method of some other, real, class.

Comment: I suppose its simply a bug / typo and the line should be `_lambda_12_32 innerLambda = __lambda_12_32{*__this};` this is how it "knows" what it is, it gets the reference passed from the line : `__lambda_10_28 outerLambda = __lambda_10_28{this};`

Comment: and if you fix the typo the code compiles: https://godbolt.org/z/9avz33K86.

Comment: *Lambda is converted into a class internally.*  That is a useful way to think about it (and it may be implemented that way by some compilers), but it is **AS IF** they were instances of an anonymous class, they don't have to be such (and the optimizer can do things that may make them not-be-such).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in cppinsight.

The line should be

```
__lambda_12_32 innerLambda = __lambda_12_32{*__this};
```

`__this` is the `this` pointer refering to the instance of `MyClass2` passed when constructing the outer lambda.

Consider that the output cppinsight shows you is not actually exactly what gcc does internally. Neither is it proper C++ code. For example all identifiers used in the output are reserved for the implementation and if you use them in user code then your code invokes undefined behavior. The output of cppinsight is produced by cppinsight, it can give you a glimpse of what the compiler does internally, but it should be taken with a grain of salt. There can be bugs.